# React native: passing in multiple parent props to child component

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, react-navigation

I have a react native application and I am trying to pass in props to my AppwithNavigationComponent. I want to do this so that the props created in Authenticator component are passed into the AppwithNavigationState component. However I am stuck on passing in multiple variables to a component:

---- index.js-----

```
render() {


        return (

          <ApolloProvider store={store} client={client}>
          <Authenticator hideDefault={true} onStateChange={this.handleAuthStateChange}
          theme={Object.assign(AmplifyTheme, styles)}>
          <AppWithNavigationState { ...this.props }/> // passing in props
          </Authenticator>
          </ApolloProvider>

        )
    }

}
export default App = codePush(App);
```

--- AppNavigator.js ------

```
const AppWithNavigationState = (props,{ dispatch, nav }) => { // trying to pass in props from parent component, get following error when I do so
  console.log(props);
 return (

  <AppNavigator navigation={addNavigationHelpers({ dispatch, state: nav })} screenProps={{ ...props }} />
)};


AppWithNavigationState.propTypes = {
  dispatch: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  nav: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  nav: state.nav,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(AppWithNavigationState);
```

^^ When I try to pass in parent props into this component, its as if the dispatch and nav components are ignored. Am I not passing in props the way I am supposed to? is there a way to pass in multiple props? if I pass in the parent props I then get the following error message:

```
Unhandled JS Exception: TypeError: Cannot read property 'index' of undefined

    This error is located at:
        in Transitioner (at CardStackTransitioner.js:60)
        in CardStackTransitioner (at StackNavigator.js:48)
        in Unknown (at createNavigator.js:36)
        in Navigator (at createNavigationContainer.js:198)
```

However if I don't try to add in the parent props then everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to change:

```
const AppWithNavigationState = (props,{ dispatch, nav }) =>
```

to:

```
const AppWithNavigationState = ({ dispatch, nav }) =>
```

Functional components by default have just a single parameter, the `props` object. If the passed in props have the `dispatch` and `nav` on the `props` object, the above destructuring syntax just gives you the `dispatch` and `nav` variables straight away.

See [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html) for examples of functional components.

Comment: I've tried this as well but props just comes back as empty.